# Set language from url?

Tags: multi-language

I used [mlanguage plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mlanguage/) for Multi language website.

How can I pass the parameters in URL?

Examples:

```
www.example.com/?lang=bm
www.example.com/?lang=en
```

Comment: Please add the URL of the plugin’s source code to your question.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/mlanguage/